# Adding autoresize to server side generated textarea using jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, textarea

Am using a plugin called "[jQuery Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize)!" on my textareas. How can i make it autoresize my server side generated textareas because they generated when the page has already loaded.

This is the code that generates the server side textareas. `resultErrorObj.node_html` contains the  server side generated textarea as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#postUpdate").submit(function(event){
      // setup some local variables
      var $form = $(this),
          // let's select and cache all the fields
          $inputs = $form.find("input"), 
          // serialize the data in the form
          serializedData = $form.serialize();
      // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
      $inputs.attr("disabled", "disabled");
      // fire off the request to /form.php
      $.ajax({
          url: base_url + "ajax/post_status_update",
          type: "post",
          data: serializedData,
          // callback handler that will be called on success
          success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    var resultErrorObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                    if (resultErrorObj.status == 1)
                    {           $(resultErrorObj.node_html).hide().insertAfter('#activitiesStream').slideDown('fast');
            }
            else
            {
                alert(resultErrorObj.error);
            }
          },
          // callback handler that will be called on error
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              // the error 
              alert("Error here " + errorThrown);
          },
          // callback handler that will be called on completion
          // which means, either on success or error
          complete: function(){
              // enable the inputs
              $inputs.removeAttr("disabled");
          }
      });

      // prevent default posting of form
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Thank you!

Comment: @timgws Oops.. I hadn't seen that part. Thank you. Now it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

The website for Autosize (http://jacklmoore.com/autosize) shows that you can manually trigger the autosizing.